# drawrect colors always wrong

Tags: ios, colors

Can someone explain to me why this is always always getting only one color (which is yellow)? The only change I could make is by changing the value of blue. If I put blue as 0, then everything becomes white. I really don't get it....I thought I would be getting a wide range of colors between red and (yellow and) green.

```
int randomNum = arc4random()%255;

int greenLevel;
greenLevel = 255-randomNum;

NSLog(@"%i",greenLevel);

if (posi==NO){
    greenLevel=randomNum;
}


CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 244, greenLevel, 30, 1);
```

Comment: I even tested it on a color slide with these values. it shows that it should work: [link]http://www.calculatorcat.com/free_calculators/color_slider/rgb_hex_color_slider.phtml

Comment: Ehm, the range of the colors **is in** CGContext's documentation...

Comment: yeah....so I was working off a tutorial, thinking that those ppl who wrote the book knows something....the original example used this: 'CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 255, 1)' so I automatically assume...anyway, the lesson is, NEVER ASSUME.

Comment: @minijera Oh, that's different, sorry. Yes, then it's absolutely a valid assumption (in this case, shame on the writer of the tutorial!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what is the greenLevel for?

Why not just use...

```
int randomNum = arc4random()%256;

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 244.0 / 255.0, randomNum / 255.0, 30 / 255.0, 1);
```

Much tidier.

Second, the range for specifying colors is from 0 to 1 so you'll need to divide your 255 colours by 255 in order to get them for iOS.

Comment: Ya, there was some crap in between that doesn't need to be shown here indeed. And thanks for catching the mistake with 255. But varying between 0-255 should produce anything from red to yellow to green for sure because of the high red & low blue levels I set. Even then, I didn't see any change. I only get one sad level of solid yellow. I imported Quartzcore already. Anything I might have missed?